# How do I repeat a string a given number of times without using the built in .repeat()?

Tags: javascript

Repeat a given string `str` (first argument) for `num` times (second argument). Return an empty string if num is not a positive number.

This is what I tried. Why does it not work?

```
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
var result = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  result += str[i];
}
  if (num>0){
    return result;
  }
  else{
    return str = "";
  }
}

repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
```

Comment: `num` does not have a `.length` property. Also, why are you accessing individual characters of the string (`str[i]`) when you want to repeat the *whole* string?

Comment: Can you please add some comments to your code to explain your approach? To me, it looks more like a `substring` method than a `repeat`.

Comment: you only use [] when you are looping through an array,  while a string can be considered an array of characters, this is not your intent.  @hev1 's response is correct.

Comment: Does my answer help?

Comment: Yes that helps. Thankyou!

Comment: @515014K Would you mind accepting my answer if it solved your issue?

Comment: I have answered my own question here using help from everyone. Would you mind up-voting it as it was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate `str` on each iteration; you are currently concatenating each character of the string to result. Also, numbers do not have the length propery and you should just compare the index with `num` itself.

```
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
    var result = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result += str;
    }
    return result;
}
```

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
    var result = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result += str;
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3));
```

You an implement this more simply by creating an array with `num` elements, filling it with `str`, and then joining it into a single string.

```
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
    return Array(num).fill(str).join('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others said, `num` has no `length` property. You just need `num`.

For gaining a bit on speed for creating really long repetitions, you could *double* the partial result repeatedly in length:

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
    if (num <= 0) return "";
    let result = str;
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i *= 2) result += result;
    return result + result.slice(0, num - result.length);
}
console.log(repeatStringNumTimes("a", 34));
```

Answer (score 0):

From this exercise I have learnt that num does not have a .length property as it is not a set of strings. Also, I have learnt that I do not need to access individual characters of the string (str[i]). Here is the the modified answer to this question using my approach. Thank-you for helping me with this question. If you could upvote this it would be appreciated as it was very helpful to me and it could be to others.

```
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
var result = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  result += str;
}
  if (num>0){
    return result;
  }
  else{
    return str = "";
  }
}

repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
```